# Call IBAction of another view controller from one viewController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to implement one thing in my project in which i want to call SecondViewController IBAction using FirstViewControllers IBAction.

Here is the code that i implement but this is not working.

FirstViewController

```
- (IBAction)StartRecording:(id)sender
{
SecondViewController *secondVC = [[SecondViewController alloc]init];
[secondVC performSelector:@selector(startStopRecording:)];
}
```

SecondViewController

```
-(IBAction)startStopRecording:(UIButton *)sender
{
// Something to do perform
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be an IBAction? Just define it like any other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, please rename your method to right naming convention. It should start with small letter which is the common industry practice.

What you are trying to do is pretty simple and straight forward.

**First:** Put `-(IBAction)startStopRecording:(UIButton *)sender` in `SecondViewController.h`

**Second:** Call it from `FirstViewController` like this:

```
- (IBAction)startRecording:(id)sender {
   SecondViewController *secondController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
   [secondController startStopRecording:sender];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You must declare the method in .h file , that you want to access.
In you example , you should declare **-(IBAction)startStopRecording:(UIButton *)sender** in .h file. And you are done

Comment: in which file? FIrstViewController.h or SecondViewController.h ?